# Problem with using ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk, arcgis

I am following this [article](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProGuide-Installation-and-Upgrade) to enable ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET in Visual Studio 2019. The Visual Studio 2019 is working in a VM (Windows 10 Home).

The ArcGIS Pro SDK has been installed successfully. However, when creating a new project using the ArcGIS Pro module Add-in, there is some problem showing the message: **This template requires a version of the .NET framework that isn't installed**.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

In the Visual Studio Installer, I have installed the `.NET desktop development` and `.NET Core cross-platform development`. And the `Visual Studio SDK` is also installed. Is there any configuration that was missing?

Please give me some help, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing `.NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack`, which is located in the `Individual components` of `Visual Studio Installer`.

[image]

Actually, the solution was presented below the error message: Please open the Visual Studio Installer to add any of the **supported .NET framework targeting packs. Compatible versions: Minimum 4.8**, Maximum 65535.255.255.